# What does the sentence "say hello to karma" mean?

Tags: meaning, irony, jokes

It's a part of a Dilbert's strip you can find 
[here](http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/100000/60000/9000/900/169988/169988.strip.print.gif):

[image: Dilbert strip]

I understand every word. But not the joke as a whole. Can you explain the irony?

Comment: I love how the guy continues to ignore him, even when he's there asking a direct question to his face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Karma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma) states that both our evil and our good acts return to us - impartial fate guides us in ways that reward or punish us according to our deeds.

The unresponsive guy is coming across Dilbert during a meeting. Dilbert berates him publicly, and uses the guy's bad karma (resulting from ignoring his emails) as an excuse to do so without any remorse.

Since Karma is a neutral, impartial force of the universe, the irony is in performing a completely conscious, subjective, petty act of revenge and claiming it's not you who is to be blamed for this act, it's the karma.

Answer (score 3):

"Say hello to karma" means "Your past has caught you up" or "You have reached the point where you cannot escape facing up to your past actions or lack of actions".

Dilbert is stating the obvious.
If it wasn't Dilbert it would hardly be funny.
 Being Dilbert it must be funny - I just haven't stared at it long enough.

Comment: Sounds very plausible. How to arrive at this interpretation? Anything helpful?

Comment: "Say hello to xxx" has become a stylised way of saying "Introducing ..." or "This is ..." as in eg "Say hello to reality". [A G' search on "SHT"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Say%20hello%20to%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) has a larghe proportion of its early hits as book or article titles of the form "SHT ...". EG SHT zORRO,  SHT Me, SHT Jupiter, SHT Satin Doll ... all with the sense of introducing or 'this is' or similar. In similar vein  SHT Karma  = This is (your) Karma, Introducing Karma (ta da!), ... .  Thus, This situation you are now in is Karma.